# ReactJs How to link a page to open with a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a website and I have created a profile page
in this profile page there are buttons ( Settings , Favourites , Posts)
I made it like a multi-step form , when you click one of those buttons it shows one of 3 pages ( each button has an onClick method that sets the page number and an if functions returns every page according to that number )
the first page that shows when you click on profile is the Settings and I have a button for favourites in the navbar and I want to link it to the profile page in a way that shows the favourites page and not the settings when I click on it.
I apologize if my question isn't clear / understandable I'm still new to web development.
Here's the code for the page display :

```
const [page,setPage]=useState(0);
const FormText=["Reglages","Mes Annonces","Favoris"]
const PageDisplay =()=> {
    if (page === 0){
        return <Reglages/>;
    }
    else if (page === 1){
        return <Mesannces/>;
    }
    else if (page === 2){
        return <Favoris />;
    }
```

this is the code for the buttons :

```
<Button onClick={()=>{setPage ((currentPage)=>currentPage=0);}} disabled={page===0}>Reglages</Button>
    <Button onClick={()=>{setPage ((currentPage)=>currentPage=1);}} disabled={page===1}>Mes Annonces()</Button>
    <Button onClick={()=>{setPage ((currentPage)=>currentPage=2);}} disabled={page===2}>Favoris</Button>
```

Comment: add your code so everyone can help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you just write a summarized question or statement with code so that people can understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

//Where your will render, inside your div

<div>
{page === 0 ? < Reglages/> : page === 1 ? < Mesannces/> : page === 2 && < Favoris />
</div>
```

Buttons

```
<Button onClick={()=>setPage(0)} disabled={page===0}>Reglages</Button>
<Button onClick={()=>setPage(1)} disabled={page===1}>Mesannces</Button>
<Button onClick={()=>setPage(2)} disabled={page===2}>Favoris</Button>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: the button will click to open the favourites ( favoris) page is in the navbar and it's on a different js file 
is there a possibility for me to send that " page === 2 " from one js file to another with the click of that button ?

Comment: You mean those three buttons are navigation menu, like navbar in html ?

Comment: They are tabs or nav links ? you want to make navigation

Comment: I have a page called profile 
in  profile I'm rendering 3 different "pages" ( Reglages,favoris,annonces) 
the buttons that will render those 3 pages exist in that profile page 
and there's another button for favoris in the navbar , I want to link that button to the profile page in a way that displays Favoris page with it 
I want it to behave as if I set the page number to 2 when I click on Favoris button in the navbar 
the navbar code is in a file called navbar.js and the profile code is in a file called profile.js I think I have to send the "page==2" data from profile.js to navbar.js ?

Comment: https://headlessui.dev/react/tabs   Take a look in this link you want to make like this?

Comment: so there are total 4 buttons? three buttons there and another favoris button on navbar?

Comment: yes ! I want the link in the favoris button on navbar to display page === 2 in the profile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes there is a way to do that, you can pass page=2 value through query parameters in url like http://localhost:8000/profile?page=2 like this, then you can get that value inside profile page by using useSearchParams() hook from "react-router-dom" v6 library.

Comment: I will show you tomorrow how to do it, or you can google/youtube it, If you can do it by urself that's great , otherwise I will tell you, I am from india so its almost morning here, i have to sleep atleast few hours  , Good Night See you soon.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'll check it out and wait for your reply tomorrow